# Eucalyptus Walrus Connection Problems

Tags: authorization, cloud-storage, request, eucalyptus

I'm beginning with Eucalyptus, with some S3 and EC2 background. I have an app for which I use a personal library to interface with S3 and store/retrieve files from there. Now I want to make my app compatible with Walrus too.

This is my setup:

Ubuntu 10.04 server UEC:

- Just installed it on a fresh VM, selecting all components but the NC, as I only need Walrus
- After boot I verified that walrus was running at `10.211.55.18:8773/services/Walrus`
- Go to `10.211.55.18:8443` web portal and changed the admin password
- From the same place I retrieved the query interface credentials (id+secret)

I was able to interact with Walrus through Cyberduck and Cloudberry without problems, I've created then a bucket 'mybucket' and an object 'myobject', but cant make a plain request with a programming HTTP library, neither using curl with generated authorization.

If I go to the browser and insert: `http://10.211.55.18:8773/services/Walrus/mybucket/myfile` I get a pretty XML message with an authorization error (as expected).

But when trying to get that object, I've done the following signing process (pseudo code):

```
digest = new_openssl_sha1_digest

date = "Sat, 03 Mar 2012 18:13:54 GMT" (now UTC datetime)

description = "GET\n\n\nSat, 03 Mar 2012 18:13:54 GMT\n/mybucket/myfile"

signature = new_base_64_HMAC(digest, secret_key, description)

headers = { 
            Date: date,  
            Authorization: "AWS <access_key_id>:<signature>"
          }
```

So then I end up with these request URL and headers:

Path: `http://10.211.55.18:8773/services/Walrus/mybucket/myfile`

Headers: `{"date"=>"Sat, 03 Mar 2012 18:13:54 GMT", "Authorization"=>"AWS WKy3rMzOWPouVOxK1p3Ar1C2uRBwa2XXXXXX:U/fpoVUCbN64h8iRICp9JZzKWgE="}`

But when I issue a GET request as above I only get a tiny response saying:

```
<headers>
Status: 400 Unauthorized
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
<body>
Failure: 400 Bad Request
```

I cannot find what I'm I doing wrong, I'm following the S3 signing process. I need to understand this as I need to implement a plugin to Walrus for my app, so I cannot use third party tools.

Hope that someone can help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found what was happening... Actually, walrus includes the /services/Walrus path on the signature too, I was only signing the /mybucket/myfile. So one can solve this by signing the string '/services/Walrus/bucket/file', thats it!